# CreateProcess() запускает не ту программу c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Starting\n";

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    memset(&si, 0, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    CreateProcess(L"old.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, false, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    cout << "Process started\n";
    TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, NO_ERROR);
    system("PAUSE");
    cout << "Process stopped\n";
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

После компиляции old.exe запустилась нормально, но после того, как я заменил имя(в программе) на new.exe и перекомпилировал, программа плевала на мои изменения: все так же запускает old.exe...

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начните с того, что почистите все бинарники в папке с программой (или Clean Solution, если работаете в студии), и посмотрим, что будет.

Comment: почистил, запускается все та же old.exe

Comment: во всех примерах что я нашел для обнуления переменной si используется не memset, а ZeroMemory(&si,sizeof(STARTUPINFO)). попробуйте

Comment: использовал сначала, потом для проверки заменил на memset, эффекта тоже ноль. Есть подозрение, что проблема из-за TerminateProcess...

Comment: @mazanax, я сейчас проверил Ваш код, все работает и в случае изменения имени программы, но: у вас процесс создается, вы пишите в консоль Process started и сразу же убиваете процесс. поставьте system("pause") перед Terminate'ом.

Comment: я сейчас тоже переписал руками все и вроде работает... странно тогда, что были какие-то проблемы

Comment: ZeroMemory [ничем не лучше](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038302/why-do-zeromemory-etc-exist-when-there-are-memset-etc-already) memset. Это просто удобная форма. Есть подозрение, что запускаете просто разные файлы (ведь студия делает release и debug версии). Или просто студия не делает полную пересборку. Попробуйте rebuild all.